# how to use subquery in order by with case in nhibernate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I need to fetch result from DB table using nhibernate with QueryOver for below sql query. The SQL request is like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Address,phone,ispassed  
FROM employee WHERE ispassed = 1   
ORDER BY   
(CASE WHEN id in (select empId from salary where empId in (2,45,65) and   Type=5) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) asc,  
Name desc
```

I am stuck in Order by. So, please give an example to construct nhibernate query for

```
ORDER BY  
(CASE WHEN id in (select empId from salary where empId in (2,45,65)  
and Type=5) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) asc
```

I have sub query as :

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<salary>()
            .Where(x => x.Type == 5 && x.empId.IsIn(2,65,45))
            .SelectList(list => list
.Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property<salary>(x => x.empId))));
```

and when I am adding subquery in main query as :

```
query.OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
            Restrictions.In(Projections.SubQuery(subquery)),
            Projections.Constant(0),
            Projections.Constant(1))).Asc();
```

It is showing error as "The best overloaded method match for 'NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.SubQuery(NHibernate.Criterion.DetachedCriteria)' has some invalid arguments."

Comment: Are you getting an error with this? What's your issue?

Comment: Actually I am new in nhibernate and stuck in order by .. how I will use subquery inside case. I have nhibernate query for order as below :
.OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
                Restrictions.Where<salary>(a => a.EmpId.IsIn(?)),
                Projections.Constant(0),
                Projections.Constant(1))).Asc().  
I want to use subquery in place of ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you want:

```
        Employee employeeAlias = null;
        var subquery = QueryOver.Of<salary>()
            .Where(x => x.Type == 5 && x.empId.IsIn(2,65,45))
            .And(x => x.empId == employeeAlias.Id) 
            .Select(x => x.empId);

        var query = session.QueryOver(() => alias)
                   .Where(x => x.IsPassed)
                   .OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
                       Subqueries.Exists(subquery.DetachedCriteria),
                       Projections.Constant(0),
                       Projections.Constant(1))
                       ).Asc
                   .ThenBy(x => x.Name).Desc
                   //.Select
                   //.List 
                   ;
```

Comment: Hi Roman , I have updated question above in reply of your answer.Thanks.

Comment: @jeet I've updated my answer according to your changes

Comment: Thanks for your update @Roman but DetachedCriteria is not available after subquery.

Comment: Which version of NHibernate do you use?

Comment: I am using nhibernate version v4.0.30319.

Comment: Hi Roman, problem resolved. I used DetachedCriteria to construct subquery and in main query the condition is like  query.OrderBy(Projections.Conditional(
                Subqueries.PropertyIn("empid", detachedsubquery),
                Projections.Constant(0),
                Projections.Constant(1))
                ).Asc();
Thanks.